# What does 23/32c mean in 700x23/32c tubes

Tags: tire, innertube

So, I use 700x23 tires on my bike. I am planning on buying a new one from the internet and on most of the tubes I see things like 700x23/32c. Does this mean that these tubes are suitable for both 23 and 32mm and if so would there be any changes in terms of performance compared to usual 700/23c ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The item in your image is a tube, not a tire. Tubes go inside tires.

That said, your intuition about the designation is correct. That tube is labeled as appropriate for tires as narrow as 23 mm and as wide as 32 mm.